# Windows Form Automation in C++ using low level WinAPI Calls?

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, winapi

I am working on a project that is supposed to take a program written in C++ using Windows forms (a basic calculator taking two ints, an operator and has an equals button) and automates it using C++ and low level WinAPI calls.

I have been googling a bit, but most of the references I find on this are fairly old and I want to make sure I'm going in the right direction. I see OLE Automation but not sure if that's the right direction

What I do know:
I cannot use Reflection, any 3rd party library including Visual Studio's UI/Testing automation assemblies.

I assume whatever I use I will launch the application, get the window by it's title, get each element by the element name somehow, simulate a click, read the calculated value, etc. It's just getting there that is the problem

Comment: Is this some kind of school assignment?  You'd normally just use a UI Automation library for this.  If this is a school project then you suspect you are supposed to use what you learned, whatever that may be.  We don't know.

Comment: No, it isn't a school assignment. It's not graded and I am encouraged in the description to use the internet for research... so here I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're familiar with the basics of window handles and such so I'll skip that part, but here are some pointers to help you get started:

To find the form's control windows - [EnumChildWindows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

To send messages to each of those windows - [SendMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Finally, a list of the messages you can send to buttons - [Button Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for your program check out the BM_CLICK message in particular)

You can find MSDN references for each of the other controls' messages by goggling "msdn edit control (etc.) messages".

Comment: Thanks! It's my first time jumping back into Win API functions and using C++ in years. Very helpful.